# KendoUI Grid footer extras from returned JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the following JSON being returned from my PHP script to populate my Kendo grid:

```
data: [{id:1, sku:-, theName:Two tier wedding veil, basePrice:77.00, dimensions:-, weight:-,…},…]
querytime: "0.0000"
rowcount: 4
```

Which works great. As you can see I have added an extra parameter called "querytime".

How do I access that on the JS side of things so I can append that to the footer of the grid?

I have tried:

```
console.log($('#productGrid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource);
```

To try and find where my extra parameter is located but to no avail.

How can I access my customer parameter?

---

```
var columns = [
    {
        field: 'dateRaw',
        title: 'Date added',
        width: '90px',
        template: '<span class="data" data-menu-id="1" data-item-id="#=id#" data-item-type="products"><abbr title="At #=time#">#=dateFormatted#</abbr></span>'
    },
    {
        field: 'sku',
        title: 'SKU',
        width: '120px'
    },
    {
        field: 'theName',
        title: 'Name'
    },
    {
        field: 'dimensions',
        title: 'Dimensions',
//width: '120px'
    },
    {
        field: 'weight',
        title: 'Weight',
        width: '80px'
    },
    {
        field: 'basePrice',
        title: 'Price',
        width: '60px',
        format: '{0:n}'
    }]

$('#productGrid').kendoGrid({
    rowTemplate: '',
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'Ajax',
                data: {
                    call: 'Product->productGrid'
                }
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: 'data',
            querytime: 'querytime',
            total: 'rowcount',
            model: {
                id: 'id',
                fields: {
                    dateRaw: {
                        type: 'date'
                    },
                    id: {
                        type: 'number'
                    },
                    sku: {
                        type: 'string'
                    },
                    basePrice: {
                        type: 'number'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 20,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        error: function(e) {
            modalError(e.errorThrown + "<br/>" + e.status + "<br/>" + e.xhr.responseText)
        }
    },
    height: 700,
    autoBind: false,
    filterable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true,
    columns: columns
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you are pretty close:
`querytime` is available inside the options object of your dataSource:

```
$('#productGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.options.querytime
```

Comment: When I console.log that I can't see my custom parameter anywhere :(

Comment: how are you initializing your kendogrid?

Comment: oh, you're using transport to get the data from the server,
I think you have no chance of intercepting the response unless you override the read function yourself:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.read